# Why does the Angular Data Table Schematic connect method operate on the source array data twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

The command `ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name=data-table`
 generates a `connect()` method that looks like this:

```
  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<DataTableItem[]> {
    // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
    // stream for the data-table to consume.
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }
```

I'm not sure exactly what this does, but it passes in `this.data` in the merge and also to `getSortedData()`.  This seems like it's doing the same job twice?  Just curious what the implementation is doing and whether there is a more efficient way to do this?

For example could the implementation of connect not just first:
- Sort the array
- Slice the the sort result to get the page
- Return an observable of the page?

It's unclear what the purpose of the merge is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge emits when any of the three observables in it emit, the map function is ignoring any value emitted by the merge so whoever wrote this used it just to create an event emitter that fires when the paginator or sort changes. Without the observableOf(this.data) it wouldn't emit the first value but seeing it ignores parameters the `observableOf` / `of` could have contained anything or they could have used a startsWith.

Comment: Of so basically the `merge.pipe` can be read as "If we have a data change, or a page change, or a sort change" then recompute the data that the table should consist of?

Comment: No, the of(this.data) will not know it the data changes, of just wraps an object in an observable but does not watch the object for changes. It will not emit if the data changes. It will cause the merge to emit instantly but if the data changes it wont trigger the merge.

Comment: Ok - so the `paginator.page` and `sort.sortChange` are the only "Live" event emitters?

Comment: I assume so but I cannot see what they are as the code for them is not in your question.

Comment: OK - I think you are right.  I was trying to think how to go about making the `of(data` live and I think we can just turn it into a behavior subject or replay subject that we can call `next` on which would allow dynamic updates to the data source.